# SQL query improvement (extra column in table)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have this query in SQL that I KNOW it is horribly written. Could you guys help me write it in a decent, normal person manner?

Thanks.

```
select distinct R.*, X.LIKED
from Recipe R
left join (select distinct R.* , '1' as LIKED 
           from Recipe R, Likes L 
           where R.id = L.idRecipe 
             and L.email = 'dvader@deathstar.galacticempire') X
on R.id = X.id
```

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: y have you written sub query ? if you write only sub Query it will give same out put

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need all from recipe with marks on liked by vader@deathstar.galacticempire

```
select R.*, likedR.LIKED
from Recipe R
left join (select distinct R.id , '1' as LIKED 
           from Recipe R 
                inner join Likes L on R.id = L.idRecipe
           where  
                L.email = 'dvader@deathstar.galacticempire') likedR
on R.id = likedR.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.

I was able to do what i wanted with this query:

```
select distinct R.*, X.LIKED, U.imgUrl 
from  User U, Recipe R 
left join 
    (select distinct R.* , '1' as LIKED 
     from Recipe R, Likes L 
     where R.id = L.idRecipe and L.email = 'dvader@deathstar.ge') X 
on R.id = X.id 
where R.email = U.email
```

This will bring all the info i need in one table plus 1 extra column with either a 1 or a null if the entry of dvader is in another table, Using joins.